# Design - same function in two controllers

Tags: codeigniter

I have two controllers in my CI apps.

- admin_controller.php, and
- user_controller.php

in `user_controller.php`, there is a function `show_message()` like this:

```
class User_controller extends Controller{    
    function show_message(){
        echo "your message";
    }    
}
```

and, in `admin_controller.php`, I want to write a function like `show_message()`.

My question, what is the best way to use one function in two controllers? Should I rewrite function `show_message` in `admin_controller.php` like this ?

```
class Admin_controller extends Controller{    
    function show_message(){
        echo "your message";
    }    
}
```

or should I create that function in file helper and call the function in controller admin and user?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
     function show_message(){
     echo "your message";
}    


Class Admin extends MY_Controller {}
Class User extends MY_Controller {}

$this->admin->show_message();   // Result: "Your message"
$this->user->show_message();   // Result: "Your message"
```